# What technology should I use to update toggle buttons only when changes in the database were committed?

Tags: javascript, ajax, togglebutton

I'm using toggle buttons to control relay switches from a webpage. I'm currently using AJAX to update the relay status when the user clicks the toggle buttons on the web page but I have also programmed a micro-controller to update the relay status on the database when the relay was switched on or off physically. I want the toggle buttons on the web page to be updated as this happens. I am currently using `setInterval()` to periodically make AJAX request to check for relay status on the database and update the toggle buttons that way. But I feel like this is making the webpage slower for I have other AJAX requests being made constantly to render and update the charts. I'm using vanilla JavaScript in this project BTW.

Answer (score 2):

WebSocket is what youre looking for; it send messages to whomever is listening, allowing your server to update the users browser when something changes. Try https://socket.io/

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out. Also, would it be a good idea to use it with the real-time charts as well or should I stick to AJAX?

Comment: Yes would go with WebSockets for anything that needs real-time data from a server